# why carousel not sliding or redirect to empty page?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, I have faced a problem while creating a carousel slide.

when I click next or previous button it redirects to an empty page. how can I resolve it?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ul>


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="../../assets/img/gaming.jpg" alt="gaming" width="100%" height="500">
    </div>
    ...

  </div>



  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create demo app in stackblitz?

Comment: remove the 'href' attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code seems to work just fine.**

I've created a demo with your code (just stubbed the img src)

> **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-carousel)
>
> ```
> <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
>
>   <ul class="carousel-indicators">
>     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
>     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
>   </ul>
>
>
>   <div class="carousel-inner">
>     <div class="carousel-item active">
>       <img src="../../assets/img/gaming.jpg" alt="gaming" width="100%" height="500">
>     </div>
>     ...
>
>   </div>
>
>
>
>   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
>     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
>   </a>
>   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
>     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
>   </a>
> </div>
> ```

**Do check if you have correct Bootstrap 4 links and scripts**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Or check if you have installed bootstrap correctly**

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

**then check your `angular.json` and add like below**

```
"styles": [   
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [  
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Comment: It did not work when I installed and imported scripts on ```angular.json```. It worked fine if I import scripts into ```index.html```, can I edit ```index.html``` is that good way?

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy it will fetch from the CDN links so it won't be a problem